# How to format a double of fixed precision to a given length?

Tags: c++, formatting

I am using the formatted output like

```
std::cout << " " << std::setw(7) << std::setprecision(5) << Value ;
```

with the goal to prepare a table. The table, however, appears like this:

```
     0  6.0303  16.052  40.523     100  40.557  16.167  6.7314  1.8967       0
     0  4.5593   13.16  25.342  41.927  25.354  13.312  4.9988  1.9527       0
     0  3.0952  6.6864  13.531   17.01  13.544  6.7291   3.466 0.91553       0
     0  1.1353   3.466  5.0842  7.3242  5.0842  3.4981  1.2207 0.56076       0
     0 0.54474 0.95825   2.153  2.1179   2.153 0.95825  0.5928 0.10681       0
     0 0.085449 0.38452 0.45166 0.78392 0.45166 0.38452 0.085449 0.048065       0
     0 0.032043 0.042725 0.15221 0.11444 0.15221 0.042725 0.032043       0       0
     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

It looks like if the first digit after the decimal point is zero, the displayd length is one character longer. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. So I wanted to do this after thinking about all the edge cases. I'm sure I don't handle some right, and I think this would be cleaner in C, but I think it's alright (if way way way over engineered).

Feel free to edit with comments if you know what's going on :).

Except a few warnings:

This is way over engineered, and way under tested.

Not portable, but can be made so with some more work.

I added an extra row of test / corner cases to your input.

This is likely way more than you need, but you can generalize this. Or use a library that does it better.

```
#include <cmath>                                                                                
#include <cstdint>                                                                              
#include <iomanip>                                                                              
#include <iostream>                                                                             
#include <vector>                                                                               

const std::vector<std::vector<double>> array = {                                                
  // OP's data.                                                                                 
    {0, 6.0303, 16.052, 40.523, 100, 40.557, 16.167, 6.7314, 1.8967, 0},                        
    {0, 4.5593, 13.16, 25.342, 41.927, 25.354, 13.312, 4.9988, 1.9527, 0},                      
    {0, 3.0952, 6.6864, 13.531, 17.01, 13.544, 6.7291, 3.466, 0.91553, 0},                      
    {0, 1.1353, 3.466, 5.0842, 7.3242, 5.0842, 3.4981, 1.2207, 0.56076, 0},                     
    {0, 0.54474, 0.95825, 2.153, 2.1179, 2.153, 0.95825, 0.5928, 0.10681, 0},                   
    {0, 0.085449, 0.38452, 0.45166, 0.78392, 0.45166, 0.38452, 0.085449, 0.048065, 0},          
    {0, 0.032043, 0.042725, 0.15221, 0.11444, 0.15221, 0.042725, 0.032043, 0, 0},               
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},                                                             
  // My test data.                                                                              
    {1e-7, 1.12031e-34, 1e-34, 1e-6, 1e33, 1e-8, 1.3123233e93, 1e32, 1.e99, 1.e100},            
    {-1e-7, -1.12031e-34, -1e-34, -1e-6, -1e33, -1e-8, -1.3123233e93, -1e32, -1.e99, -1.09e100},
};                                                                                              

// Warning: any widths under 7 cannot accurately print the double -1e+100...                    
// (or many like it). There's just no way to express that any more tersely!                     
constexpr uint8_t kWidth = 7;                                                                   
// Most of these are really obvious but help make the code slightly cleaner.                    
// "."                                                                                          
constexpr uint8_t kWidthTakenByDecimalSeparator = 1;                                            
// "-"                                                                                          
constexpr uint8_t kWidthTakenByNegativeSign = 1;                                                
// "e+" or "e-"                                                                                 
constexpr uint8_t kWidthOfExtraScientificNotationCharacters = 2;                                
// On *MY* system, 1.0e-08 is always printed, not 1.0e-8. This basically handles                
// the leading 0 on the exponent. Tune accordingly (or find the right compiler                  
// flags that give you the right number(s).                                                     
constexpr uint8_t kMinimumWidthOfScientificNotationExponent = 2;                                

int main() {                                                                                    
  // Store the original std::cout flags.                                                        
  auto old_flags = std::cout.flags();                                                           
  for (auto& row : array) {                                                                     
    for (auto& value : row) {                                                                   
      const double log10_value = log10(std::abs(value));                                        
      const uint8_t available_width = kWidth - (value < 0) * kWidthTakenByNegativeSign;         
      // Handle numbers greater than 10^kWidth or less than 10^-kWidth in                       
      // scientific notation.                                                                   
      const bool use_scientific_notation =                                                      
          value != 0 &&                                                                         
          (log10_value < -1.0 * available_width + kWidthTakenByDecimalSeparator +               
                             kWidthTakenByNegativeSign ||                                       
           log10_value > available_width);                                                      
      std::cout << ' ' << std::setw(kWidth);                                                    
      if (use_scientific_notation) {                                                            
        const double log10log10_value = log10(log10_value);                                     
        const uint8_t num_digits_in_exponent_of_scientific_notation =                           
            std::max(kMinimumWidthOfScientificNotationExponent,                                 
                     static_cast<uint8_t>(log10log10_value ));                                  
        const uint8_t num_digits_desired_after_decimal_scientific =                             
            std::max(1.0, log10log10_value);                                                    
        uint8_t potential_new_precision =                                                       
            available_width - num_digits_in_exponent_of_scientific_notation -                   
            kMinimumWidthOfScientificNotationExponent -                                         
            kWidthTakenByDecimalSeparator -                                                     
            num_digits_desired_after_decimal_scientific;                                        
        // Lazy underflow checking. Needed?                                                     
        if (potential_new_precision > available_width) {                                        
          potential_new_precision = 0;                                                          
        }                                                                       
        std::cout << std::scientific                                            
                  << std::setprecision(potential_new_precision);                
      } else {                                                                  
        // We take the max with 1.0 to compensate for the leading 0 in decimals.
        // If your system doesn't put a leading zero there, remove it.          
        const uint8_t number_of_digits_before_decimal_fixed =                   
            std::max(log10_value + 1.0, 1.0);                                   
        const uint8_t number_of_digits_desired_after_decimal_fixed =            
            available_width - kWidthTakenByDecimalSeparator -                   
            number_of_digits_before_decimal_fixed;                              
        // Fixed width decimals -- this means that the code                     
        //   std::cout << std::precision(n)                                     
        // tells the stream to use n digits *after the decimal*.                
        std::cout << std::fixed                                                 
                  << std::setprecision(                                         
                         number_of_digits_desired_after_decimal_fixed);         
      }                                                                         
      std::cout << value;                                                       
    }                                                                           
    std::cout << '\n';                                                          
  }                                                                             
  // Reset the flags to their old value, and flush the output buffer.           
  std::cout.flush();                                                            
  std::cout.flags(old_flags);                                                   
}
```

And the fun stuff:

Example output with kWidth=7:

```
0.00000 6.03030 16.0520 40.5230 100.000 40.5570 16.1670 6.73140 1.89670 0.00000
0.00000 4.55930 13.1600 25.3420 41.9270 25.3540 13.3120 4.99880 1.95270 0.00000
0.00000 3.09520 6.68640 13.5310 17.0100 13.5440 6.72910 3.46600 0.91553 0.00000
0.00000 1.13530 3.46600 5.08420 7.32420 5.08420 3.49810 1.22070 0.56076 0.00000
0.00000 0.54474 0.95825 2.15300 2.11790 2.15300 0.95825 0.59280 0.10681 0.00000
0.00000 0.08545 0.38452 0.45166 0.78392 0.45166 0.38452 0.08545 0.04806 0.00000
0.00000 0.03204 0.04272 0.15221 0.11444 0.15221 0.04272 0.03204 0.00000 0.00000
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
1.0e-07 1.1e-34 1.0e-34 1.0e-06 1.0e+33 1.0e-08 1.3e+93 1.0e+32 1.0e+99  1e+100
 -1e-07  -1e-34  -1e-34  -1e-06  -1e+33  -1e-08  -1e+93  -1e+32  -1e+99 -1e+100
```

Example output with kWidth=10:

```
0.00000000 6.03030000 16.0520000 40.5230000 100.000000 40.5570000 16.1670000 6.73140000 1.89670000 0.00000000
0.00000000 4.55930000 13.1600000 25.3420000 41.9270000 25.3540000 13.3120000 4.99880000 1.95270000 0.00000000
0.00000000 3.09520000 6.68640000 13.5310000 17.0100000 13.5440000 6.72910000 3.46600000 0.91553000 0.00000000
0.00000000 1.13530000 3.46600000 5.08420000 7.32420000 5.08420000 3.49810000 1.22070000 0.56076000 0.00000000
0.00000000 0.54474000 0.95825000 2.15300000 2.11790000 2.15300000 0.95825000 0.59280000 0.10681000 0.00000000
0.00000000 0.08544900 0.38452000 0.45166000 0.78392000 0.45166000 0.38452000 0.08544900 0.04806500 0.00000000
0.00000000 0.03204300 0.04272500 0.15221000 0.11444000 0.15221000 0.04272500 0.03204300 0.00000000 0.00000000
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
0.00000010 1.1203e-34 1.0000e-34 0.00000100 1.0000e+33 0.00000001 1.3123e+93 1.0000e+32 1.0000e+99 1.000e+100
-0.0000001 -1.120e-34 -1.000e-34 -0.0000010 -1.000e+33 -1.000e-08 -1.312e+93 -1.000e+32 -1.000e+99 -1.09e+100
```

That was more than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
std::cout << std::fixed;
```

The default behaviour is to display the number of digit in "precision". The std::fixed is to display to exact number of digits. So On default you will display 5 significant numbers. On fixed, 5 numbers.
For example:

```
auto a = 2017.0;

default = 2017
fixed = 2017.00000

auto b = 1e-10;

default= 1e-10

fixed = 0.00000
```

Comment: I think that fixed, setw and setprecision are conflicting attributes. What is their relation?